# Apache POI Docx - insert img in existing document Header

Tags: apache-poi

I need to insert an img in the header of an existing docx.

My code:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("test.docx"));

XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerPolicy = docx.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.getDefaultHeader();
XWPFParagraph parNew = header.createParagraph();
parNew.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
XWPFRun run = parNew.createRun();  
String pathImg="FILE/logo/logo_top.jpg";
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pathImg);
XWPFPicture picture = run.addPicture(
    in,
    XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG,
    "logo",
    Units.toEMU(150), Units.toEMU(50));
    in.close();
String blipID = "";
for(XWPFPictureData picturedata : header.getAllPackagePictures()) {
    blipID = header.getRelationId(picturedata);
    System.out.println("blipID: " + blipID);
}
picture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip().setEmbed(blipID);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test_headerImg.docx");
docx.write(fos);
```

When i open the docx modified i get an "Error in opening file" error.

Thanks for any help.